# Shouldn't Kang be concerned when the Secret Service agent does not return?

Tags: olympus-has-fallen

The Secret Service agent who was the traitor informed Kang that Banning was dead. After that the agent did not return to Kang for a long time. Shouldn't Kang, who was a wicked mastermind, have doubted his delay to return? The agent also had a radio. Kang could have contacted him to enquire about the delay.

Comment: Meh, he maybe should, but didn't. So what?

Comment: @ChristianRau, I wanted to know if there is any explanation behind his foolish behaviour what I might be missing. If there is not (_better say nobody is able to find one_), well then, I guess there isn't an answer :P

Comment: I think there are many *opinion based* answers here ... mine would be arrogance.

Comment: I would just say it's a plot hole in a movie filled with them.

Answer (score 2):

The wicked mastermind had other things on his mind like the military, the Cerberus codes, and the unification of the Koreas (for example). He also had a number of men under his command and the return of one man might not have been deemed important enough for him, turncoat though he may have been.

In any event, he doesn't really need Forbes any longer.